# How to implement Scaffolding in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

"I am using spring maven project and want to implement Scaffolding in it so that I can generate DAO's, services and spring form dynamically depending upon model. How it can be achieved?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, spring roo generates view as .jspx pages which uses Dojo and Dijit (I don't understand why roo didn't use Jquery). Roo is very much restrictive to editing the generated view files.

So if you scaffold using roo, you would find your hands are strongly tied (just as mine now is).

My suggestion is, build your models as you wish, but for scaffolding, you should use JSF or GWT. Both are better than using Dojo. Both are available as spring roo add ons. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). As this offers what you are searching.

Comment: I have gone through above link... but didnt get exact process for developing roo project.. Can anybody tell how to create this type of project in STS??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Most questions should be answered here: http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo - In short, you use the interactive roo shell, type commands in there, and spring roo will generate and do all needed stuff for you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at this tutorial : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

It explains how to generate a full web application (Spring MCV - JPA or Spring Data) from a database

It uses a free Eclipse plugin named "Telosys Tools" (a code generator with scaffolding)

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Telosys** http://www.telosys.org

It's very efficient for scaffolding (from database or from specific model)
You can customize the templates in order to generate exactly what you want

See also https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

Answer (score 0):

There is a good Scaffold for Spring Boot you can use for startup: https://github.com/runlala/SpringBootScaffold